# If i run this program even if i give the input as 0 it countinuosly getting the values in it?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void main()
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };
    struct node *head,*temp;
    int x;
    clrscr();
    head=(struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        scanf("%d",x);
        temp->data=x;
        if(x==0)
        {temp->next=NULL;}
        else
        {temp->next=(struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));}
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

I was writing a code for a simple linke list program ... I can successfully run the program but when I press 0 the program is not stopping..

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: Please let us know what book or tutorial told you to use `void main()`? Its author doesn't know C very well. The correct definition is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Use `scanf("%d", &x)`

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, your scanf is wrong. it needs to be passed by reference:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Secondly, you should set x to something other than 0 before scanf'ing it, just in case. The way it is written, you have no exit condition in your loop.

You could try using gdb and stepping it line by line if you want to get right into it.

Hope this helps

Comment: In C, there's no pass by reference. The correct terminology is "passing a pointer to x".